# Using variables in function parameters, with or without Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, meteor, parameters

I would like to write a function that I could reuse with different elements.

The idea is to get the window height and apply it to different elements.

I thought I could do something like this but it doesn't work:

```
function autoHeight(element) {
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  $(element).css('height', height);
}

autoHeight('.dashboard-sidebar');
autoHeight('.some-element');
```

It doesn't work.  I know I'm close, but I'm missing something!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you are just missing the 'px' when you get the height from window.innerHeight. The rest seems ok.

Comment: you can alternatively skip the "px" requirement by just doing `$(element).height(height)`

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be working fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/gerLe2x9/

Have you wrapped your JS in `$(window).load`:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    function autoHeight(element) {
       var height = window.innerHeight;
       $(element).css('height', height);
    }

    autoHeight('.dashboard-sidebar');
    autoHeight('.some-element');
}
```

Comment: Oh.... Forgot to mention it's in a Metor app!!

So I guess I should add it to a Template.templateName.onRendered....!

Comment: @Neonjack I haven't personally got experience with meteor, but looking at this: http://docs.meteor.com/#/basic/Template-onRendered that appears to be the equivalent place, if you know what I mean.

Comment: Totally!  It works now, thanks :)  Even though it didn't explicitly answered my question, it helped me solve it!

Comment: @Neonjack no dramas. You were pretty much there as your code was fine, just needed to put it in the correct place.

Answer (score 0):

**With JavaScript**

```js
function autoHeight(element) {
  var height = window.innerHeight;
  var ele = document.querySelector(element);
  if (ele) {
    ele.style.height = height + 'px';
  }
}

autoHeight('.dashboard-sidebar');
autoHeight('.some-element');
```

```css
div {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  background: #DDDDDD;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="dashboard-sidebar"></div>
<div class="some-element"></div>
```